# Erro PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by, mas para deletar o cookie da página depois de exibi-lo

Tags: php, cookies, header, warnings

Eu sei que já existe perguntas sobre esse erro, mas preciso de uma ajuda por não conseguir resolver, mesmo com as informações sobre o erro.
Estou fazendo um site que define um cookie para mostrar um erro e depois que mostra, ele deleta, no entanto, para excluir o cookie, tem de ser depois de exibir, só que dá esse erro, e se excluir antes, ele não mostra o erro.

Exemplo:

```
if($envio){ $mensagem = "Houve um erro no envio!"; }
else { $mensagem = "Enviado com sucesso!" }
setcookie('mensagem', $mensagem);
```

E na hora de exibir o erro:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['mensagem'])){
echo "<div class='alert'>";
echo $_COOKIE['mensagem'];
echo "</div>";
setcookie('mensagem'); }
```

Mesmo tentando trocar o 'setcookie()' por 'unset()', não consigo fazer com que ele apague o cookie.

**Obs: estou fazendo tudo numa landing page**

Comment: Recomendo ler com atenção a postagem linkada acima, pois o que está explicado lá se aplica perfeitamente ao seu caso. Se deu qualquer saída de conteúdo, não tem mais como dar redirect nem setar cookies (é o mesmo processo, o uso de headers). A solução é fazer tudo que precisa com header antes de mostrar coisas na tela, e deixar o echo para o final do script. É mera questão de reorganizar seu código.

Comment: Resolvi sem cookie, pois a questão de reorganizar da forma que eu queria, não daria, porque teria de mostrar o erro e só depois apagar, e como os headers não podem ser modificados após serem enviados, não dá pra apagar. Mas obrigado.

Comment: Lembre-se que você tem o META REFRESH, que também permite delay (mas precisa ser posto no head).

Comment: Para 5 segundos de espera: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://endereco/">`

Comment: Tem alternativa de usar um JS também. De qualquer forma, é sempre bom um link discretinho (nem que seja cinzinha) com o clássico "clique aqui se não for redirecionado em X segundos", pra pessoa não ficar "Presa" na página caso alguma restrição impeça o refresh.